# Is there a way to use other fonts, besides the default ones in OpenGLUT?

Tags: opengl, c++, fonts, glut

I'm using OpenGLUT functions like glutBitmapString to render sentences and words in a game. However, there is a limited set of fonts to use and I need some bigger size fonts. Is there a way to add new fonts to these functions/API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Freetype OpenGL, a library for displaying a unicode text using a (single) vertex buffer and freetype fonts. Have a look at their [**web**](https://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/), [**repository**](https://github.com/rougier/freetype-gl) and [**documentation**](http://freetype-gl.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/doc/index.html).

An example, from their website:

```
    /* Text to be printed */
    wchar_t *text = L"A Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog 0123456789";

    /* Texture atlas to store individual glyphs */
    texture_atlas_t *atlas = texture_atlas_new( 512, 512, 1 );

    /* Build a new texture font from its description and size */
    texture_font_t *font = texture_font_new( atlas, "./Vera.ttf", 16 );

   /* Build a new vertex buffer (position, texture & color) */
    vertex_buffer_t *buffer= vertex_buffer_new( "v3i:t2f:c4f" );

    /* Cache some glyphs to speed things up */
    texture_font_load_glyphs( font, L" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?"
                                     L"@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_"
                                     L"`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

    /* Where to start printing on screen */
    vec2 pen = {0,0};
    vec4 black = {0,0,0,1};

   /* Add text tothe buffer (see demo-font.c for the add_text code) */
    add_text( buffer, font, "Hello World !", text, &black, &pen );
```

Comment: It is extremely hard to install `freetype-gl`. I use Ubuntu. Full of mysterious installation obstacles.